# on clicking button Jquery alert event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">

    <title>Jquery alert example</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
          jQuery('#event').click(function(){
            alert("hello world");
          });
        });
        </script>
        <input type='button' id='event' class='btn btn-success' value='click me'>
      </div><!--container ends here-->
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I am clicking on alert button event is not working. I have attached jQuery file also. One more doubt for me does jQuery syntax need to change if I upgrade from jQuery version 1 to version 3. Please notify me where I am doing a mistake and guide me how I can avoid this problem.

Comment: Its because you jquery click event is placed before you include jquery i think.

Move your click event below `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: put the script tag before the end of body tag.

Comment: Always make sure that `JQuery` code should be placed after the including of `JQuery Library` elsewhere your `Jquery` will not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes put your jquery library at the top before your jquery code. It will work and the proper way of writing events is:-

```
   jQuery('#event').on('click', function(){
            alert("hello world");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the following `script` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('#event').click(function(){
        alert("hello world");
      });
    });
</script>
```

under the jQuery script tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First import basic .js file after write code for jquery:

```
$('#btnID').click(function(){
alert('welcome')
});
```